# actionbarsherlock ics spinner drop down width overlapping in android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner

I am using [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) `IcsSpinner` for supporting drop down in 2.2 and it's working fine, but when there is a big text shown in drop down item list like following preview in image.

[image]

The spinner drop down width is overflowing, as shown in below image.

#### spinner define in layout.

```
 <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/prop_spnr_state"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spnr_bg" />
```

#### raw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_entry"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

#### set spinner in Java.

```
  QuestionAdapter adapter = new QuestionAdapter(
                                        LoanInfoActivity.this,
                                        R.layout.question_textview, quesArrayList
                                                .get(i).getArrayList());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: try `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`